# Tensorflow 2.2: How to use the memory optimizer option in grappler?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I would like to use the memory optimizer option of the graph optimizers as describe [in tensorflow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/graph_optimization) in order to prevent `out of memory` errors.

I do not understand how to use it. I checked the `tensorflow` documentation but this option did not appear with the other available [see here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/config/optimizer/set_experimental_options).

Could someone explain why it did not appear ? Is this option available?

I see that this option have some related code in the tensorflow's souce code (see [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.2.0/tensorflow/python/grappler/memory_optimizer_test.py)).

Does it mean that this option is not available officially yet? Is there a way to use it ?

Comment: Explaination and example of `tf.config.optimizer.set_experimental_options` is given in the [Tensorflow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/graph_optimization). Could you elaborate your problem statement. Thanks!